# Pickling an object as an instance of its parent class?

Tags: python, pickle

Suppose I had the following subclass that I'm using to temporarily endow `list` with some extra methods,

```
class MyList(list):
   def some_function(self):
       pass
```

and then I do something like

```
>>> f = MyList()
>>> .. bunch of list stuff ...
>>> cPickle.dump(f,open('somefile','w'))
```

Now, that is all well and good until I try to open the file

```
>>> cPickle.load(open('somefile'))
```

and I get a complaint that `MyList` doesn't exist. Is there a way to somehow
get `MyList` to pickle as a plain `list` so that when I later try to load
the pickle file, I don't get this missing class error? I would like the pickle file to only refer to the built-in `list` type.

Comment: Why not fix the missing class issue by having your module available for import when unpickling (with `MyList` as a global in that module)?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances)?

Comment: You can customise what is pickled, yes, there are various hooks, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances

Comment: Seems like the easiest fix would be to use `pickle.dump(list(f), open('somefile', 'w'))`

Comment: @mgilson Yes, but the Mlist object is embedded into other objects so I would have to unpack and re-pack them to get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I need more help than I can get from that page. Also, this is a Python 2.7 issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The trick is that MyList has methods for doing one-off debugging and other forensics. I don't want to have to distribute and support it because it's not important to the final product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you wanted to do is to pickle the class instance and bundle up the class description in the pickled object.  `pickle` doesn't pickle a class description, but `dill` does.

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...   def some_function(self):
...     pass
... 
>>> f = MyList()
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dump(f, open('somefile','w'))
>>>
```

And then upon loading, it just works...

```
dude@hilbert>$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 12:42:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> f = dill.load(open('somefile','r'))
>>> f
[]
>>> type(f)
<class '__main__.MyList'>
>>> g = f.__class__()
```